# Error: Cannot find control with name: Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, funciones

Estoy intentando hacer un reactive form en Angular 8 pero al hacer la relación en el HTML obtengo 2 errores.

La idea es recorrer unos datos de tipo boolean y crear controles de tipos checkbox, los crea pero me salen esos errores, cuando recargo la pagina ya no me salen los errores y los crea con los valores que trae cada dato.

```
 errorres
 1) Cannot find control with name: 'nombre del control que se estoy creando'**
 2) Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined**
```

archivo  ts

```
    export class GenericInputComponent<T> {
    @Input()
    formField: FormField<T>;
    @Input()
    form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
   formFields: FormField < FraudControl > [] =[
   {
     name: 'pool',
     label: 'pool_fraud_control',
     placeholder: 'Pool',
     type: 'text',
     validators: [Validators.required],
   },
  ];
constructor() {this.createcontrol;}
createcontrol(nameParam: string, fraudList: any) {
 let title = this.addcapitallettersandspaces(nameParam);
 var obj = {};
 obj[nameParam] = fraudList[nameParam];
 let control = this.formFields.push({ name: nameParam, label: title, type: 'checkbox', 
 placeholder: title, disabled: true });
 return control;
 }
}
//nameParam: Nombre del control a crear.
//this.formFields: Formulario al cual le vamos a hacer el push
```

Ese es un control creado estaticamente al cual se le agregara el dinamico que quiero hacer, la siguiente funcion la inicializo en el constructor.

mi html

```
    <form #mainForm appChildFormSubmit appParentFormSubmit [formGroup]="form">
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="formField.type">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="checkboxInput;context:{$implicit:formField}"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #selectcheckboxInput let-item>
    <div class="select-wrapper">
        <select [appFormError]="!item.disableError" [onlyIfSubmitted]="getOnlyIfSubmitted(item)"
            class="{{ getInputClasses(item) }}" [name]="item.name" [formControlName]="item.name"
            [required]="getRequired(item)" (change)="capturar($event.target.value)">
            <option value="" disabled class="hidden">{{ item.placeholder | translate }}</option>
            <option *ngFor="let option of item.selectOptions" [value]="option.value">{{ option.label | translate }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Alguna suguerencia para dejar de tener este error ?? desde ya gracias.

Comment: Mmmm hay cosas que no me quedan claro en tu código, en tu *HTML* tienes `[formGroup]="form"`  ¿donde instancias el *form* en tu *TyspeScript*? o bueno en todo caso la pregunta seria donde esta la instancia del *FormGroup*

Comment: @Israel-ICM  Lo edite me habia faltado esa parte del codigo al generar la pregunta.

Comment: Bien según veo al instanciar `form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});` se encuentra vacío, por lo mismo no puedes usar el `formControlName` porque no hay ningún control instanciado en el form, debería haber un control algo como: `form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({miControl: new FormControl('')});` y así podrías usar `formControlName='miControl'` en el *HTML*.

Comment: Básicamente el error **`Cannot find control with name:`** se da porque no existe el nombre del control que buscas en el `form`

Comment: Para el otro error que tienes me parece que también te falta subir alguna porción de código.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!